Is this sentence correct? "Dass"-clause
Is this sentence correct:
"Persönlich denke ich, dass die geistige Gesundheit wichtiger ist als die körperliche Gesundheit."
Shouldn't the verb, "is" be at the end of dass clause?
P.S.: Google suggested this sentence but I'm not sure it is correct.

Maybe I think i wasn't very clear with my quiestion...the part that i'm strugling to understand is that the position of verb did change in the sentence, but it isn't at the end of sentence ...."A ist wichtiger als B." changed to ",dass A wichtiger ist als B."....why not ", dass A wichtiger als B ist.

Oh i didn't know that... thank you

The comparative construction ("als ...") is described as being capable of both being placed before as well as being placed after verbal phrases.
Hence you can have both:


Ich habe gesagt, dass ich den Krieg schlimmer [als den von 2014] finde.
Ich habe gesagt, dass ich den Krieg schlimmer finde [als den von 2014].


I won't screenshot from the Duden grammar reference book due to copyright. But you can find pictures of the so-called "Feldermodell" that is used to analyse the phrase sequence in German.

Source:
Wöllstein, Angelika and Bibliographisches Institut, editors. Duden - Die Grammatik. 10th ed., Dudenverlag, 2022, p. 97.
